# How to see if Apache Derby is installed and running?

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am using an application framework that requires the use of Apache Derby database with Java JDBC. I would like to know if there is a simple command I can use at the command line in bash to see if Derby is installed and running.

Answer (score 2):

Derby doesn't get "installed".

Derby is packaged as a set of Java libraries, which you can embed into your own application.

Derby does come with its Network Server, but that is just a Java program which you can run, not a service which is installed.

So really all you have to do is to have Derby in your CLASSPATH when you run your program.

If you want to check your classpath, try doing

```
java org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo
```

which will print a diagnostic report about the Derby libraries that it finds on your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use OS command like:
ps aux | grep derby

This command will show which process is running for Derby

Answer (score 0):

See Apache Derby Installation Guide.

Embedded Derby :
 https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#set_derby_install

Derby Network Server :
 https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

If Linux, you can check it using the following command

```
 sudo netstat -nlp | grep :1527
```

where 1527 is your derby port number.